# How to get rid of whitespace in the yellow portion?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function Chat(id) {
  function resize() {
    var chat_emb = $("#" + id);
    var height = $(window).height() - 19;
    var width = $(window).width() - 19;
    chat_emb.height(height);
    chat_emb.width(width);
    var boxw = chat_emb.width() / 1.20;
    var boxh = chat_emb.height();
    var boxtop = (boxh / 5) / 90;
    boxleft = (boxw / 5) / 90;
    var box = $("#cmsgs")
    var input = $("#input")
    var ulw = width - boxw
    var ulh = chat_emb.height() + 3;
    var ul = $("#ul");
    var rightul = (ulw + boxw - width) + 10
    //check if box has a height
    //if it does then no need to make element
    if (box.height()) {
      box.css("position", "absolute");
      box.css("top", boxtop);
      box.css("left", boxleft)
      box.height(boxh)
      box.width(boxw);

    } else {
      var box = document.createElement("div");
      box.id = "cmsgs";
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(box);
      var box = $("#cmsgs")
      box.css("position", "absolute");
      box.css("top", boxtop);
      box.css("left", boxleft);
      box.height(boxh)
      box.width(boxw);
    }
    if (!input.height()) {
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.setAttribute("id", "input");
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(input);
      input = $("#input")
      input.width(boxw - 5)
      input.css("position", "absolute");
      input.css("left", boxleft);
      input.css("bottom", boxtop);
    } else {
      input = $("#input")
      input.width(boxw - 5)
      input.css("position", "absolute");
      input.css("left", boxleft);
      input.css("bottom", boxtop);
    }

    if (ul.height()) {
      ul.height(ulh + 3);
      ul.width(ulw);
      ul.css("postition", "absolute");
      ul.css("right", rightul);
    } else {
      var ul = document.createElement("div");
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(ul);
      ul.id = "ul";
      ul = $("#ul");
      ul.height(ulh + 6);
      ul.width(ulw);
      ul.css("position", "absolute");
      ul.css("right", rightul);
    }
  }
  resize();
  //resize event
  $(window).bind("resize", function() {
    resize()
  });
  $(document).bind("resize", function() {
    resize()
  });
  var box = $("#cmsgs");
  box.css("background-color", "gray");
  var input = $("#input")
  input.css("background-color", "#0FF");
  var ul = $("#ul");
  ul.css("background-color", "#FF0");
  ul.css("padding", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  ul.css("margin", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  box.css("padding", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  box.css("margin", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
Chat("chatbox")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chatbox"></div>
```

As you can see when you run the snippet the yellow part has a lot of whitespace. How can i get rid of it? I know this might be hard to understand because the code is kinda crammed in there. So, if you have any trouble understanding ill explain more.
I've tried to set margins and paddings to 0 but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try below code. Few changes in your code

```js
function Chat(id) {
  function resize() {
    var chat_emb = $("#" + id);
    var height = $(window).height() - 19;
    var width = $(window).width() - 19;
    chat_emb.height(height);
    chat_emb.width(width);
    var boxw = chat_emb.width() / 1.20;
    var boxh = chat_emb.height();
    var boxtop = (boxh / 5) / 90;
    boxleft = (boxw / 5) / 90;
    var box = $("#cmsgs")
    var input = $("#input")
    var ulw = $(window).width() - boxw
    var ulh = chat_emb.height() + 3;
    var ul = $("#ul");
    var rightul = (ulw + boxw - $(window).width())
    //check if box has a height
    //if it does then no need to make element
    if (box.height()) {
      box.css("position", "absolute");
      box.css("top", boxtop);
      box.css("left", boxleft)
      box.height(boxh)
      box.width(boxw);

    } else {
      var box = document.createElement("div");
      box.id = "cmsgs";
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(box);
      var box = $("#cmsgs")
      box.css("position", "absolute");
      box.css("top", boxtop);
      box.css("left", boxleft);
      box.height(boxh)
      box.width(boxw);
    }
    if (!input.height()) {
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.setAttribute("id", "input");
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(input);
      input = $("#input")
      input.width(boxw - 5)
      input.css("position", "absolute");
      input.css("left", boxleft);
      input.css("bottom", boxtop);
    } else {
      input = $("#input")
      input.width(boxw - 5)
      input.css("position", "absolute");
      input.css("left", boxleft);
      input.css("bottom", boxtop);
    }

    if (ul.height()) {
      ul.height($(window).height());
      ul.width(ulw);
      ul.css("postition", "absolute");
      ul.css("right", rightul);
    } else {
      var ul = document.createElement("div");
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(ul);
      ul.id = "ul";
      ul = $("#ul");
      ul.height($(window).height());
      ul.width(ulw);
      ul.css("position", "absolute");
      ul.css("right", rightul);
    }
  }
  resize();
  //resize event
  $(window).bind("resize", function() {
    resize()
  });
  $(document).bind("resize", function() {
    resize()
  });
  var box = $("#cmsgs");
  box.css("background-color", "gray");
  var input = $("#input")
  input.css("background-color", "#0FF");
  var ul = $("#ul");
  ul.css("background-color", "#FF0");
  ul.css("padding", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  ul.css("margin", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  ul.css("top", 0);
  box.css("padding", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  box.css("margin", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
Chat("chatbox")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chatbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#chatbox{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}

#cmsgs{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-color:grey;
  width:80%;
  height:95%;
}

#input{
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:5%;
  width:80%;
  background-color:rgb(0,255,255);
}

#ul{
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  background-color:yellow;

}
```

```html
  <div id="chatbox">

    <div id="cmsgs"></div>

    <input id="input">

    <div id="ul"></div>
  </div>
```

```
 #ul{
        position:absolute;
        height:100%;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        width:calc(100%-(width of grey block)px); //assuming you want a specific pixel width
        background-color:yellow;
    }
```

calculate or set the width of the grey block so that it is known (i would set it with a css percentage).

use that to calculate the width of the yellow block.  this can be done in several ways using javascript or css.

Comment: Could you please explain, too, what your CSS is doing? (for future readers)

Comment: I suppose you should edit your answer and delete this comment as comments are not permanent (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). I will delete mine then too

Answer (score -1):

Rather than absolute positioning, you can use `position:relative` on the parent div, and use a simple float: right.

This way, you wouldn't even need to know the width of anything in advance.